# Syntax for filters for aws rds describe-db-instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

When we run the command using filters we are getting the error:

```
$ aws rds describe-db-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the
DescribeDBInstances operation: Unrecognized filter name: instance-state-name.
```

What is the correct syntax for using filters for `aws rds describe-db-instances`?

Answer (score 10):

Your syntax seems to be fine, but `instance-state-name` is simply not a valid filter for RDS.

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html):

```
--filters (list)

A filter that specifies one or more DB instances to describe.

Supported filters:

    db-cluster-id - Accepts DB cluster identifiers and DB cluster Ama-
    zon Resource Names (ARNs). The results list will only include
    information about the DB instances associated with the DB Clusters
    identified by these ARNs.

    db-instance-id - Accepts DB instance identifiers and DB instance
    Amazon Resource Names (ARNs). The results list will only include
    information about the DB instances identified by these ARNs.
```

As something like `instance-state-name` doesn't exist for RDS I assume what you're searching for instead is [`DBInstanceStatus`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Status.html). While it's not possible to use `--filter` to filter for that, you can use `--query`:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[?DBInstanceStatus==`available`]'
```

The difference between `--filter` and `--query` is that `--filter` directly influences what's sent back by the API, while `--query` does some local filtering of the results received from the API. As long as you don't have a very large amount of RDS instances, `--query` should work fine for you.

Comment: HI if there any way to filter the output fields .aws rds describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[?DBInstanceIdentifier==`xyz`]"   --query "DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceArn,Engine,DBInstanceIdentifier,EngineVersion,Address]"

Comment: Yes, you can use the `--query` option for that as well. Check out the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html

Comment: Specify `--query` only once, like:
`aws rds describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[?DBInstanceIdentifier==xyz].[DBInstanceArn,Engine,DBInstanceIdentifier,E‌​ngineVersion,Address‌​]"`

Comment: Is there any way to get the header information when we try to get the output in table format.
C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI>aws rds describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].[Engine,DBInstanceIdentifier,EngineVersion,Endpoint.Address,AllocatedStorage,DBInstanceClass,Endpoint.Port]"

Answer (score 0):

Adding quotes should work

example:

```
aws rds describe-db-cluster-endpoints --db-cluster-identifier=aurora-cluster-dev  --query 'DBClusterEndpoints[*].[Endpoint]' --filters 'Name=db-cluster-endpoint-type,Values=writer'
```